How to Combine one agent to agent the convey?
This is my model.
I wanna use moveBycrane to move agent1(engine) from source1 to the agent2(car) on convey without stopping at positionOnConveyor.
Is there anyway to combine two agents on convey without Node?

I found that when I set the Destination as conveyor2.getAgents().get(0)
It works sometime.

Sorry, I struggle to understand what you want to achieve, can you clarify and delete the irrelevant stuff (database...). thx

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
